# How to execute ng-if before a directive or use something else than ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem here is that the directive gets executed before the ng-if. 
How can i manage to execute the ng-if before the directive?

Am i doing something wrong ? Should i use something else than ng-if to show/hide divs?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2wdSnTJHVQbD3fK3O8N?p=preview
script.js

```
lolModule = angular.module('lolModule',[]);
lolModule.directive('initTest', function(){
    return function($scope, $element){
        console.log("test",$element.html());
    };
});

lolModule.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.testExpr=function(e){
    console.log("bool=",e);
    return e;
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="lolModule">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div init-Test>
      <div ng-if="testExpr('true')">if is true</div>
      <div ng-if="testExpr('false')">if is true</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can pass the expression into the directive instead of using ng-if

Comment: Do you want something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/LgKsdjlQfxdb9rUVmvXy?p=preview

Comment: @V31 not realy. 
What i want to do is show/hide the div(which in my real application contains alot of stuff in it) And at the same time if the if is shown i do sth with the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs to actually return something, otherwise it will always return undefined (which is falsy), and that's why none of your `ng-if`s get triggered.

For example:

```
lolModule.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.testExpr=function(e){
    console.log("bool=",e);
    return e == 'true';
  }
});
```

See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gPizAfnD0BrmHFAfcNyu?p=preview

Comment: my bad about that but it doesn't change the fact that the directive gets executed before the ng-if

Comment: I misread this, so you want the directive to be executed later, even though it comes first in the DOM? Isn't that normal behaviour?

Comment: If you see my code above(i changed it form v1) when you see the console log, the directive shows the html and the ng-if didn't execute yet so it shows the html commented. (What i basicaly want to do at that point is find an element in that div and retrieve some data, but i can't because the ng-if didn't execute yet)

Comment: The Angular way would be to use a scope variable to build HTML, not the other way round. So, you'd do something like: `<div init-Test ng-init="exprResult = testExpr('true')">` and then do the desired behaviour based on the `exprResult` value. Hiding those divs inside would work independently.

Comment: I found my way around it. I'll just have to create a new directive for the individual div. That way the moment the div is shown the directive gets exectued also. Your ides helped me alot thx. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the other way to do it. It's important to leave the independent things to be independent. :) Glad I could help.